# I need $(".className").each(function () with div. I can only get it to work with input

Tags: jquery

The following jQuery code works if my tag is:

```
<input class="AmountElementValue" readonly="readonly" />
```

However, it does not work if I make the input a `<div />`. The code is:

```
$(".AmountElementValue").each(function () {
    alert($(".AmountElementValue").val());
    var TrimedAmountElementValue = $(this).val().replace(/\$/g, '');
    TrimedAmountElementValue = TrimedAmountElementValue.replace(",", "");
    totalDisbursement += parseFloat(TrimedAmountElementValue);
});
```

How can use a `<div />` instead?

Answer (score 5):

`.val()` does not work on `<div />`s; perhaps you want `.text()` or `.html()`?

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` is only defined for input elements. Use `.text()` instead for a div.